# How to close comments with just 1 click?

Tags: comments, nodes

My site editors want a quick way to close comments on a particular node, i.e. they just want to click a button on an item, rather than having to click edit, then select the comment settings tab, then click the "closed" box.  (This is for Advanced forum, but I guess it could apply anywhere).

I have a feeling this should be fairly easy to do but I can't work out how to do it. Any pointers you can give would be appreciated. (I am using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module and thought flag actions would be a simple way to do this, but closing comments doesn't seem to be an available action).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by following steps given below:

1. Create a flag on nodes for administrator only
2. Add new rule using Rules module
3. Set React on in Event "A node has been flagged, under
4. Add action "Set a data value"
5. Select Data "flagged-node:comment"
6. Click Continue and set value as 0

Please check Rule given below(exported):

```
{ "rules_disable_comments" : {
    "LABEL" : "Disable comments",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "flag" ],
    "ON" : { "flag_flagged_disable_comments" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "flagged-node:comment" ], "value" : "0" } },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Comments closed" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

& Flag given below(exported):

```
$flags = array();
// Exported flag: "Disable comments".
$flags['disable_comments'] = array (
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'title' => 'Disable comments',
  'global' => '0',
  'types' => 
  array (
    0 => 'article',
  ),
  'flag_short' => 'Disable comments',
  'flag_long' => '',
  'flag_message' => '',
  'unflag_short' => 'Enable comments',
  'unflag_long' => '',
  'unflag_message' => '',
  'unflag_denied_text' => 'Disabled comments',
  'link_type' => 'toggle',
  'weight' => 0,
  'show_in_links' => 
  array (
    'full' => 'full',
    'teaser' => 'teaser',
    'rss' => 0,
    'search_index' => 0,
    'search_result' => 0,
    'token' => 0,
  ),
  'show_as_field' => 0,
  'show_on_form' => 0,
  'access_author' => '',
  'show_contextual_link' => 0,
  'i18n' => 0,
  'api_version' => 3,
);
return $flags;
```